# how to know which file compile when I run npm run dev

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, npm, npm-run

when running npm running its compile CSS and js right? where can I find that file and can I edit it, I want to change the background of my vue2-timepicker, its currently in `#dde1e3`, I want to change it to `#fff` / white, and also when I'm using vue2-timepicker, it automatically became read-only, anyway thank you so much, everyone, hope someone can help me thank you so much in advance

Comment: can you explain step by step ? add the commands you're typing and what you're getting vs expecting.

Comment: Usually there is a `webpack.mix.js` file in your Laravel project root that defines what to do. But I doubt you can change/set colors there

Comment: Have you tried setting an [input-class](https://github.com/phoenixwong/vue2-timepicker/blob/master/README.md#the-input-class) attribute to your own defined class?

Comment: Not yet sir, Ill try now, and thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when running npm running its compile css and js right?

`npm run dev` means *Run the command listed under `dev` in the [`scripts` section](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts) of package.json*.

That could do pretty much anything (and compiling CSS and JS is one thing it could do).

So to determine what it is doing, look at package.json to see the command and trace through.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I'll let you know whenever it works, thank you so much again

Comment: It work, I traced it, thank you so much for your help, now my problem is veevalidate, its not working, ahahaha, anyway thank you so much again for your help